# Is this 'all' a pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, quantifiers

> Three boys entered, and Harry recognized the middle one at once: it
>   was the pale boy from Madam Malkin's robe shop. He was looking at
>   Harry with a lot more interest than he'd shown back in Diagon Alley.
>   
>     "Is it true?" he said. "They're saying **all** down the train
>   that Harry Potter's in this compartment. So it's you, is it?"
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘all’ a pronoun and indicating ‘they’? If yes, why does it separated from they and be placed in the middle of the sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check out these written instances of

> [...saying all over town...](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22thought%20Wow%20What%20had%20he%20thought%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22saying%20all%20over%20town%22&oq=%22saying%20all%20over%20town%22&gs_l=serp.3...2390933.2398353.0.2398712.22.22.0.0.0.1.393.1646.18j3j0j1.22.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.qLHNXtCyKYo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=dba990302fc18104&biw=1512&bih=907)

...you'll see that sometimes it's a *singular* subject - such as [[**he**] has been saying all over[the country]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22thought%20Wow%20What%20had%20he%20thought%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22has%20been%20saying%20all%20over%22&oq=%22has%20been%20saying%20all%20over%22&gs_l=serp.3...76423.77155.6.78011.5.5.0.0.0.0.74.313.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.ysOLFhJ69ss&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=dba990302fc18104&biw=1512&bih=907). Clearly, the word *all* modifies the *location* (the train, in OP's case), not the speakers.

The sentence doesn't specify how *many* people are saying that HP is in this compartment - we know it's more than one (since "they" is plural), but it could be anywhere between *two*, and *every single person*.

Also note that constructions like *all down the train, all across the country, all over town* don't often mean *in every **single** part*. Usually they mean *in **many different places** scattered throughout the named area*.

Comment: Exactly. And it's *all **down** the train* rather than *all **over** the train* because a train's all over is basically one-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

*All* would be referring to *they* if the phrase were "they are all saying." "All down" in "they are saying all down the train that […]" means they are saying that to everybody in the train.

Comment: Actually, I think in this case it means that everybody in the train is saying that (although the only way to decide between the two interpretations is from context).